# Executing Remote file on Remote Server using Powershell

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I'm trying to execute a file remotely using powershell, from a remote server.

I'm running the following (with real server names etc substituted):

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer someserver -Force

$credential = Get-Credential -Credential currentdomain\currentuser

$RemoteSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName someserver -Credential $credential -Authentication Credssp

Invoke-Command -Session $RemoteSession -ScriptBlock { Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server    -Force }

Invoke-Command -Session $RemoteSession -ScriptBlock { New-PSDrive -Name I -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\servername\sharename$ }

Invoke-Command -Session $RemoteSession -ScriptBlock { Invoke-Expression($args[0]) } -ArgumentList (I:\executablepath\file.exe)
```

I know I'll have to do this afterwards to tidy up:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $RemoteSession -ScriptBlock { Disable-WSManCredSSP -Role server}

Disable-WSManCredSSP -Role client

Remove-PSSession $RemoteSession
```

1. I'm getting an error after the `New-PSSession` line, although I think this worked the first time I tried it. I may be wrong though.

   > Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request because the server name cannot be resolved.
   >       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [], PSRemotingTransportException
   >       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionOpenFailed
2. Is there another approach that I should be using to achieve this overall requirement? I've tried without using credentials but think I need these to avoid the 2nd hop problem.

Comment: Where is the second hop occurring?

Comment: I was assuming the second hop was either when I was mapping the "I" drive via the remote session, or remotely running the executable via the mapped drive. Correct me if I'm wrong though...

Comment: I believe that's correct.  You can avoid needing CredSSP if you just copy the executable to the target computer from your main script first, and then execute it from a local path.

Comment: Thanks. Afraid that's not really an option. The exe I'm running is part of a very large install package, so I'd prefer to be able to run it remotely. Can you see what I'm doing wrong with the CredSSP?

Comment: Not really seeing anything wrong, but we don't allow CreddSSP for security reasons, so I don't have much practice with it. Is this a one-off deal, or something that you'll run regularly?

Comment: Something regular enough that we want to get it right and running efficiently. Did you have anything in mind?

Comment: Either a schedule task (run on demand using a script) or a constrained session using delegated (RunAs) credentials: http://ramblingcookiemonster.wordpress.com/2013/07/20/granular-access-via-powershell-remoting/

Comment: Oh good lord, I've just realised the servername I was using was wrong...Thanks for your help and sorry for the inconvenience